# g++ : command not found in angstrom on beagleboard

Tags: beagleboard, angstrom-linux

I am using angstrom on beagle board.. but when I try to run any command on the terminal I get this error:

Sh:g++:not found

I tried installing g++ Using opkg install g++ but no use!!

Comment: Try run `/usr/bin/g++`? If that fails try reinstalling. 
If that succeeds you have some issues with your `PATH` variable.

Answer (score 2):

Do `opkg install task-native-sdk` or, if you only need g++, `opkg install g++-symlinks`.

Comment: I used `opkg install g++-symlinks`, which solved my immediate problem, but when I tried to do a `make` on a node module, it gave me an error: `g++: error trying to exec 'cc1plus': execvp: No such file or directory`. Does installing symlinks leave out anything important? Also, installing `task-native-sdk` didn't work for me. Opkg just gave me a `Couldn't find` error.

Comment: Sorry, cannot tell for sure now. You can use [opkg search](https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/techref/opkg) to see what package provides `cc1plus`, or `opkg list | grep g++` to look for `gcc` packages in general. Third way is to `find / -name cc1plus` and to create the symlink yourself. No promises on linker, tho.